# Empty line treatment when reading tables in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have the problem that in some scenarios plots from tables are not drawn if empty lines are in the read input file. Boundaries etc. are drawn and set correctly and no errors are shown in the log.

Let's directly start with the MWE

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data1.txt}
0 0

1 1
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{data2.txt}
0 0
1 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

  \addplot [color=black] table[x index =0, y index = 1,]   {./data1.txt}; 

  \addplot [color=red,very thick,dashed] table[x index =0, y index = 1,]   {./data2.txt}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

and the outcome

[image]

The desired outcome would of course contain two identical lines:

[image]

When the same is done with `pgfplotstableread`, both command work fine (i.e., both datasets work). But for large datasets, this is not an option.

Somehow, the simple `table {filename}` has problems with an empty line inside table data. Interestingly, this does not occur if the first `\addplot` does not receive and options (not even empty ones `[]`).

Is this desired behavior? Is there an option to ignore empty lines also when reading tables like done in the MWE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To weed out empty rows you only need to say `empty line=none`, see p. 45 of the manual.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{data1.txt}
0 0

1 1
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{data2.txt}
0 0
1 1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

  \addplot [color=black,empty line=none] table[x index =0, y index = 1]   {./data1.txt}; 

  \addplot [color=red,very thick,dashed] table[x index =0, y index = 1]   {./data2.txt}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh i know. (I tried to mention in the text that this works). But for large data it is not very practical. (The manual says the macro version is slower from 200 entries on)

Comment: @Faekynn Oh, sorry, I misread this. Then I do not know an answer but personally I feel that, if you want to deal with huge data sets and want to have high performance, you may want to weed these empty lines out with some faster tools like perl or something of that sort.

Comment: Perl, sed and so are of course possible, but not that portable. I guess it should be possible though: writing just `addplot table {file}` surprisingly works. Only once i add a plot option, the graph disappears. So, in some cases it is treated correctly...

Comment: Maybe somebody else knows with a deeper understanding of the pgfplots interna...

Comment: @Faekynn I completely revised the answer. You only need to say `empty line=none`.

Comment: Great! Dont know why i overlooked this option, the manual is too long :D thanks a lot!

Comment: @Faekynn I better do not tell you how I found it. (I was going through the filters, and there was a statement "BTW, if you want to do something with empty lines, look here" ... ;-)